# Gridsearch n_jobs=-1 and RandomForestRegressor n_jobs=-1 not using loky workers properly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, joblib, gridsearchcv

Currently I run the follow code from my `model.py`

```
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, random_state=42, 
n_jobs=-1, criterion='mse')
print('gs start')
# run grid search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model,
                           param_grid=param_grid,
                           cv=5,
                           scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                           verbose=True,
                           n_jobs=-1,
                           refit=True)
```

with the command `nohup python -u model.py &`

Then using `top -c` I monitor the process.

I can see all of the workers run once I start the process with a subset of my data, but if I try to use all of my 6 million observations the process 
outputs `[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 128 concurrent workers.`

starts on multiple workers then after a while only uses 1 core. If i only use ~200k observations the process uses all cores. Why can the large dataset not use all the cores?

Comment: if the workers run out of memory does this kill parallelization and revert to single core?